# my users not null but showing cannot read user.name

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

when I try to fetch all the `post.user.name` it shows error like

**Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')**

I just wanna display all the user in my node

Although `user` is not null when I write like `post.user` it shows me result like

```
{ _id: new ObjectId("632eab0e9b9ae6bbb44fce38"), email: 'temp@gmail.com', password: '1', name: 'sahil ', createdAt: 2022-09-24T07:00:30.925Z, updatedAt: 2022-09-24T07:00:30.925Z, __v: 0 }
```

In above `name` is present

So why it show error when I do `post.user.name`

#### Below all the code

##### home.ejs->

```
<section id="feed-posts">
    <h4>Posts</h4>
    <% if (locals.user) { %>

        <form action="/posts/create" id="new-post-form" method="POST">
            <textarea name="content" cols="30" rows="3" placeholder="Type Here..."></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Post">
        </form>

        <div id="posts-list-container">
            <ul>
                <% for(post of posts){ %>

                    <li>
                        <p>
                            <%= post.content %>
                                <br>
                                <small>
                                    <%= post.user.name%>
                                </small>
                        </p>

                    </li>

                    <%} %>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <% } %>
</section>
```

In above code `post.content` and `post.user` work fine but `post.user.name` showing error. Although it contain `name`.

##### index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const app = express();
const port = 8000;
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
const db = require('./config/mongoose');
// used for session cookie
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const passportLocal = require('./config/passport-local-strategy');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
const sassMiddleware = require('node-sass-middleware');


app.use(sassMiddleware({
    src: './assets/scss',
    dest: './assets/css',
    debug: true,
    outputStyle: 'extended',
    prefix: '/css'
}));
app.use(express.urlencoded());

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(express.static('./assets'));

app.use(expressLayouts);
// extract style and scripts from sub pages into the layout
app.set('layout extractStyles', true);
app.set('layout extractScripts', true);




// set up the view engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', './views');

// mongo store is used to store the session cookie in the db
app.use(session({
    name: 'codeial',
    // TODO change the secret before deployment in production mode
    secret: 'blahsomething',
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: (1000 * 60 * 100)
    },
    store: new MongoStore(
        {
            mongooseConnection: db,
            autoRemove: 'disabled'

        },
        function (err) {
            console.log(err || 'connect-mongodb setup ok');
        }
    )
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(passport.setAuthenticatedUser);

// use express router
app.use('/', require('./routes'));


app.listen(port, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(`Error in running the server: ${err}`);
    }

    console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

##### Controllers/home_controller.js

```
const Post = require('../models/post');

module.exports.home = function (req, res) {
   

    // populate the user of each post
    Post.find({}).populate('user').exec(function (err, posts) {
        return res.render('home', {
            title: "Codeial | Home",
            posts: posts
        });
    })

}
```

##### controllers/posts_controller.js

```
const Post = require('../models/post')

module.exports.create = function (req, res) {
    Post.create({
        content: req.body.content,
        user: req.user._id
    }, function (err, post) {
        if (err) { console.log('error in creating a post'); return; }

        return res.redirect('back');
    });
}
```

##### config/mongoose.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/codeial_development');

const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, "Error connecting to MongoDB"));


db.once('open', function () {
    console.log('Connected to Database :: MongoDB');
});


module.exports = db;
```

##### models/post

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'

    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

const Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
module.exports = Post;
```

##### models/user

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});


const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

##### P.S:-

###### As per @Ogoh.cyril

when I log `Post.find({}).populate('user').exec(function (err, posts) { console.log(posts)})`
and instead of writing `post.user.name`(which give error) I replace it with `post.user` in my `home.ejs` file.

I got the below output

```
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("63355014bd69c27e240429b7"),
    content: 'hi mere bhai',
    user: {
      _id: new ObjectId("632eab0e9b9ae6bbb44fce38"),
      email: 'sahilgagan227temp@gmail.com',
      password: '1',
      name: 'sahil ',
      createdAt: 2022-09-24T07:00:30.925Z,
      updatedAt: 2022-09-24T07:00:30.925Z,
      __v: 0
    },
    createdAt: 2022-09-29T07:58:12.104Z,
    updatedAt: 2022-09-29T07:58:12.104Z,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("63355047bd69c27e240429bf"),
    content: '1st comment on that',
    user: {
      _id: new ObjectId("632eab0e9b9ae6bbb44fce38"),
      email: 'sahilgagan227temp@gmail.com',
      password: '1',
      name: 'sahil ',
      createdAt: 2022-09-24T07:00:30.925Z,
      updatedAt: 2022-09-24T07:00:30.925Z,
      __v: 0
    },
    createdAt: 2022-09-29T07:59:03.972Z,
    updatedAt: 2022-09-29T07:59:03.972Z,
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

#### Please help me......

Comment: to check `post.user` is null or not i have changed the code from `post.user.name` to `post.user`


 which show me output in browser like this :-
`
***{ _id: new ObjectId("632eab0e9b9ae6bbb44fce38"), email: 'temp@gmail.com', password: '1', name: 'sahil ', createdAt: 2022-09-24T07:00:30.925Z, updatedAt: 2022-09-24T07:00:30.925Z, __v: 0 }***
`

Comment: could you log `Post.find({}).populate('user').exec(function (err, posts) {})` - `posts`

Comment: I have updated u can see above code

Comment: Sorry @sahil  gagan You misunderstood me I asked for the logged gotten from here `Post.find({}).populate('user').exec(function (err, posts) { console.log(posts)})`

Comment: @Ogoh.cyril So sorry I am actually new to this... ya I have update the code u can check last-one. And thanks for taking your time into this. I hard stuck for like 2 days :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update package -> `connect-mongo`

Then change the code of `index.js`->

```
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');


store: MongoStore.create(
        {
            mongoUrl: 'mongodb://localhost/codeial_development',
            mongooseConnection: db,
            autoRemove: 'disabled'

        }
```

## It will work 100%